# Access embedded images

Tags: c#, .net, gmail-api

We are using the GMail Api in a C# application, and have received a message with an embedded image.
You can see the image if you look at the GMail account (in a browser as a user) but I am unable to find it either in the Payload or get an attachment id when I use the api.

Does the api even support accessing embedded images?

If I use:

```
var part = message.Payload.Parts
                            .Where(x => x.MimeType.Equals(mimeType))
                            .Select(x => x.Body.Data)
                            .FirstOrDefault();
```

With the Mime type set to Gif,Jpeg or Tiff it always comes back null;

Comment: You are using some sort of .Net API here, please tag your question with that.

Comment: When you're passing in mime-type as `Gif, Jpeg or Tiff` are you passing them as a proper `image/gif` mime-type? maybe try `x.MimeType.Contains("image")` to get all the image formats.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the - [Users.messages: get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get)

> Gets the specified message.

To be familiar on the structure specially when reading the email message Resource representations. I used the [Try it now](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get#try-it) to get the [Users.messages resource](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages#resource) in the response body and how it will be formed.

When checking the email, the embedded image will fall in the payload.

```
........
    {
        "partId": "1",
        "mimeType": "image/png",
        "filename": "pasted1",
        "headers": [
         {
          "name": "Content-Type",
          "value": "image/png; name=pasted1"
         },
.........
```

This is how it should look like.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Guys thanks for your prompt replies. So I did a little more checking this morning. We have got two emails in both cases they appear to have embedded images. In one case it is a "image/png" and also has part.Body.AttachmentId so all good, I can extract it out using the api. In the other case (which prompted the question) if I iterate over all of the parts there is no image, yet when you look at this email in GMail in the browser you can see an embedded image (which also appears to be a png). May be there is some sort of bug in the Api.